Multiple errors occurred with Texmaker after upgrading system
After I upgraded system to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS ,TeXmaker, which I am using, does not compile anything, even my old files. Specifically, I get the errors:
Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `lgrenc.def' not found.

LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `LGR' unknown.

LaTeX Error: File `physics.sty' not found.

Any suggestions?
Update
I installed the package which is below and the problem solved if I do not include the fontenc T2A.(which I was using mechanically and still do not know what it does.)

sudo apt-get install texlive-science


What does tlmgr info greek-fontenc say?

If you aren't short on disc space, do yourself a favour and install a complete texlive. This will avoid these and any future problems with missing packages.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz How can I see that? If you mean the compiler output I cannot see It since I installed the package i mentioned.

What do you mean with "that"?

I meant  the tlmgr info greek-fontenc

You run the command in a terminal, which should give you some output starting with package:     greek-fontenc ...

It said TLPDB: not a directory, not loading,  and tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation. Also, thank for suggesting to install texlive-full.

mm, these linux packages really don't seem very helpful. As said above, you could install a full texlive version and avoid such problems.

(or use a vanilla texlive version from tug.org )

I already did and hope i do not encounter something similar, thank you.

You're welcome!

T2A is cyrillic encoding so you need it if you are writing in a language using Cyrillic script but don't need it if you are not. (but your warnings are about Greek)
